# magento get product list for a category

Tags: magento

I have products with type simple and configurable,
But i want to get only parent products but not the child products(i.e configurable products it self contain multiple items)

I am able to getting all the assigned products for a category:

```
$category = $this->_initCategory($categoryId);
       $storeId = $this->_getStoreId($store);           
       $collection = $category->getProductCollection()
                    ->addCategoryFilter($category)
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array(
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::DEFAULT_TYPE,    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable::TYPE_CODE))                         
                    ->load();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to mage development but try:

**

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load('*')
->getProductCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'configurable'))
->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
->setOrder('entity_id','DESC');
```

**

This should hopefully produce all the configurable products that are enabled :)